# Gmail Push Notification using PHP

Tags: php, push-notification, gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

Reading the Gmail API docs, I noticed that the [Gmail API provides a way to push notification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) to a backend endpoint URL. The idea is to call process() in our backend when a user receive a new email (avoiding the pulling method).

I created a new suscription ([Cloud Pub/Sub API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console)) and I tested publishing a new message from the Cloud Platform Console. The API works like expected. But now, I don't know how to notify to Gmail API to start to watch changes of the user's INBOX. We can use `watch()` and `stop()` in Python, but what about PHP?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google discovery service APIs are simple rest APIs.  You can use them with any language capable of preforming a HTTP Post and HTTP Get.

Google is very good about making things easer for developers so they have created a number of open source client libraries to help developers.   The [Google APIs PHP Client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) is one such library.  it handles most of the hard work for you.

I would check out the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) tutorial first then move on to [User.watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) after you have your authentication flow working.

Answer (score 0):

Code example using HTTP POST:

```
// Google API
$client = getClient();

// Variables
$user = 'me';
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken()['access_token'];
$topic_name = 'projects/xxxx/topics/xxxx';

// POST request    
$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' . $user . '/watch');

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        'topicName' => $topic_name,
        'labelIds' => ["INBOX"]
    ))
));
```

It's neccesary [to grant publish privileges](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/cloudpubsub/topicList) to `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`.

[image]